# Erläuterungseinschub klingt gewöhnungsbedürftig. Ist das falsch?

Tags: grammar

Nehmen wir folgenden Satz:

> Falls du am Wochenende vorhast dein Rad zu putzen, meine Kette braucht auch eine Reinigung und ich würde eventuell mitmachen.

Man hört sofort, dass man in der geschriebenen Sprache so ein Konstrukt vermeiden würde. In *Neu-Sprech* hätte ich das Komma auch rigoros durch drei Punkte ersetzt, weil die sich an der Stelle besser anfühlen.

Eigentlich ist *meine Kette braucht auch eine Reinigung* auch kein richtiger Einschub, denn dann müsste der Basis-Satz

> Falls du am Wochenende vorhast dein Rad zu putzen, würde *ich* eventuell mitmachen.

lauten mit veränderter Position des Subjekts.

Frage: Warum genau ist dieser Satz falsch. Die einzige sinnvolle Erklärung, die ich habe ist, dass das Komma eigentlich ein Punkt sein müsste. Dann fehlt aber beim ersten Satz was, weil das *Falls* noch eine Lücke aufreißt, die geschlossen werden will.

Comment: Ich würde einen Doppelpunkt setzen:

    Falls du am Wochenende vor hast dein Rad zu putzen: Meine Kette braucht auch eine Reinigung, und ich würde eventuell mitmachen.

Comment: ich würde den Satz beenden mit ... denn meine Kette[..].

Comment: @userunknown Ja, es muss wohl *vorhast* heißen. Ich editiere das mal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im Wesentlichen hast du das Problem selber angesprochen. Der Satz fühlt sich vor allen Dingen deswegen falsch an, weil er semantisch nicht ganz sauber ist.

"Meine Kette braucht (auch) eine Reinigung" ist genau genommen die Begründung dafür, warum du auch mitmachen würdest. Das "auch" ist streng genommen hier sogar insofern falsch, weil a) nicht gesagt ist, dass das Rad dreckig ist und b) "eine Kette reinigen" bei genauerem Betrachten ein anderes Reinigen ist als "ein Rad zu putzen". If you know what I mean.

Es gibt theoretisch mehrere Ansätze, das Problem zu lösen.

Meiner Meinung nach ist die beste Lösung, wenn der Satz wie folgt laute:

> Falls du am Wochenende vor hast, dein Rad zu putzen, würde ich eventuell mitmachen, weil meine Kette auch eine Reinigung braucht.

Issue b) ist damit zwar immer noch nicht aus der Welt geräumt, aber das ist sowieso nichtig und außerdem sind die Zusammenhänge nun korrekt formuliert.

Eine Alternative ist sicherlich der Doppelpunkt. Meiner Ansicht nach fällt deine Problemstellung aber nicht zu den [typischen Anwendungsgebieten eines Doppelpunktes](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Doppelpunkt.html?lang=en).

Die Auslassungspunkte sind möglich. Diese stehen dann für "dann sag mir Bescheid":

> Falls du am Wochenende vor hast, dein Rad zu putzen, sag mir Bescheid. Meine Kette braucht eine Reinigung und ich würde eventuell mitmachen.

Falls deine Intention also ist, die Auslassung dieser impliziten Aufforderung zu kennzeichnen, kannst du zu diesen greifen.

Und nicht zuletzt kannst du auch den Gedankenstrich verwenden, wenn du den ersten Teil als vorangestellten Zusatz deklarierst. Use case: Nehmen wir an, ihr hättet kurz vorher darüber gesprochen und du greifst das Thema wieder auf.
Ganz sauber ist das aber auch nicht. Sehe ich ähnlich kritisch wie den Doppelpunkt; es ist eher schlecht als recht.

Comment: Danke für die Ausführliche Antwort. Ich hätte vielleicht erwähnen sollen, dass es sich um eine Fahrradkette handelt; der unappetitlichste Teil beim Putzen eines Rades. Deshalb hier: "Rad putzen" = Rad + Kette + ... wobei ich mir nur meine Kette vorgenommen hätte :) Anyway, big +1

Comment: Ich denke, die Bedeutung des ursprünglichen Satzes ist: Für den Fall, dass Du am Wochenende Dein Rad zu putzen vorhast, möchte ich Dich wissen lassen, dass meine Kette auch eine Reinigung braucht und ich eventuell mitmachen würde.